# Referenced library isn't copied

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, reference

I have **ProjectA(WPFApplication)** that references **ProjectB(ClassLibrary)**.
Inside **ProjectB** i have wpf window that uses control from **ThirdParty.dll** wich i accordingly reference from **ProjectB**.

The problem is that it doesn't find **ThirdParty.dll** in output folder of **ProjectA** and xaml parse runtime exceprion is raised.
There is no **ThirdParty.dll** in GAC.
Copy Locally is set to true.
It works if i manually add in output folder of **ProjectA** that library and it also works if i use that **ThirdParty.dll** somwhere right in my cs files.

How can i solve that?

Comment: Look at the properties of your reference and check if Copy Local is set to true.

Comment: @the_ajp: you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that visual studio only copies resources to the output folder if Copy Local is set. Just set the reference to Copy Local and you should be fine.

Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on how this works.

When you reference ProjectA, the references from ProjectB is not automatically referenced. For this to work, you need to add a reference to ThirdParty.dll from ProjectA as well if you only use it in XAML. The compiler does not copy references that are only used in XAML. But if you use them in code, they are copied.

This is the same issue as discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d9594ea7-c345-464c-a87f-1eef22127f8e)

Comment: I see but isn't it strange that other libraries which types are referenced as well in ProjectB are copied but this one isn't? Or it isn't copied only if it is used only in xaml and not used directly in .cs code?

Comment: @Vladimir What kind of libraries are this? Are they referenced from ProjectA?

Comment: Class Libraries. They are referenced only from ProjectB.

Comment: @Vladimir I just checked this and updated my answer. You need to use the library in c# code (not xaml) for it to be automatically copied.

Comment: I ran into this in a WCF project.  It appears that .NET will generally not copy referenced assemblies if it doesn't see a direct reference in your own code.  E.G. if 2 internal libraries reference each other, but your code only directly uses 1 library.  The result is the 1 library is copied.  Resulting in a runtime error. Considering hard drive space these days this seems like a poor optimization by .NET

Comment: Adding code reference for XAML element can be done by applying the Name attribute

Answer (score 1):

You should add the reference to the thrid party dll to the project where you want it to appear in the output directory. If the Copy Local is then set to true it will appear in you bin directory whether or not you use it in code or xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to **ProjectB.csproj**:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="...\path\ThirdParty.dll">
      <Link>ThirdParty.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This convinces VS to copy **ThirdParty.dll** to the output folder of **ProjectA**, too
(no need to add anything to **ProjectA** about **ThirdParty.dll**).
I still find it inadequate because if **ThirdParty.dll** is in a NuGet package, its path usually contains version number, which will change when you update the package.
I haven't tried it yet but I don't expect from NuGet to update the path here as it does in `<Reference>`.