# Why third party library "ChilkatDotNet4x64" isn't copied to the output folder?

Tags: c#, .net, chilkat, chilkat-email

I have project A that references third party library `ChilkatDotNet4.dll`. My project B references project A. After the compilation the output folder of B contains `ChilkatDotNet4.dll` as exptected! But, when I replace `ChilkatDotNet4.dll` to `ChilkatDotNet4x64.dll`, so the later isn't copied to the output folder. Why?

**Copy Local** is set to True, solution is compiled to **Any CPU**

At first I thought it must be something with **Copy Local** (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305953/referenced-library-isnt-copied)), but hey(!) it does work with `ChilkatDotNet4.dll` version. So what is the problem with `ChilkatDotNet4x64.dll`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Build Template make sure to add the file manually. A work around if you can't find what a build template is, is to rename the file from `ChilkatDotNet4x64.dll` to `ChilkatDotNet4.dll`

Comment: make sure you update your reference in the project as well if you do change the name